# how to make a fast pairwise Tanimoto distance function in R

Tags: r, performance, distance

I have a data.frame of items identified by an integer property `ID`, which is also the row number of the data.frame.
Each item has a vector of features `FP` associated to it. The elements of each `FP` are unique (within that `FP`). So for instance `c(1,2,7)` but never `c(1,7,7)`.

The Tanimoto distance between any two `ID`'s is defined as 1 minus the number of unique elements in the intersection of their `FP`'s, divided by the number of unique elements in the union of their `FP`'s.

I need to calculate such distances in the context of a 'maxmin' algorithm. See for instance [this blog post](http://rdkit.blogspot.com/2017/11/revisting-maxminpicker.html).

The most important point to note is that I must **NOT** compute a full distance matrix (even with the best algorithms it would be unfeasible on the scale of datasets I am working with).
As explained in the above post, the strength of the iterative maxmin picker according to Roger Sayle's method is that one can avoid computing most of the pairwise distances, and instead calculate only the few relevant ones. Hence my question.

Here's what I could come up with so far:

```
# make a random dataset

set.seed(1234567)
d <- sample(30:45, 1000, replace = T)
dd <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, sapply(d,function(n) list(sample(as.character(1:(45*2)), n, replace = F)), simplify = F))), "FP")
dd["ID"] <- 1:NROW(dd)

# define a pairwise distance function for ID's

distfun <- function(ID1,ID2) {
  FP1 <- dd$FP[[ID1]]
  FP2 <- dd$FP[[ID2]]
  int <- length(intersect(FP1,FP2))
  1 - int/(d[ID1]+d[ID2]-int)
}

# test performance of distance function

x <- sample(dd$ID, 200, replace = F)
y <- sample(dd$ID[!(dd$ID %in% x)], 200, replace = F)

pairwise.dist <- NULL

system.time(
  for(i in x) {
    for (j in y) {
      dij <- distfun(i,j)
      #pairwise.dist <- rbind(pairwise.dist,c(min(i,j),max(i,j),dij))
    }
  }
)   
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.86    0.00    0.86
```

**Question 1** : do you think the distance function could be made faster?

I tried making a sparse matrix of the features (`ddu.tab` in the code below, where I omitted the denominator, which is trivial to compute from the intersection) and defining the distance function as vector operations, but that was *much* slower (a bit to my surprise, I must say).

```
ddu <- do.call(rbind, sapply(dd$ID, function(x) {data.frame("ID"=x, "FP"=dd$FP[[x]], stringsAsFactors = F)}, simplify = F))
ddu.tab <- xtabs(~ID+FP, ddu, sparse = T)
system.time(
  for(i in x) {
    for (j in y) {
      dij <- t(ddu.tab[i,]) %*% ddu.tab[j,]
      #pairwise.dist <- rbind(pairwise.dist,c(min(i,j),max(i,j),dij))
    }
  }
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  32.35    0.03   32.66
```

**Question 2** : actually less important than the distance calculation, but if anyone can advise... The update of `pairwise.dist` by `rbind` is (apparently) very costly. I don't know if I can do it differently (meaning not adding new elements at each iteration), because in the maxmin application the pairs of `ID`'s whose distances are to be calculated are not known upfront like in this example, and `pairwise.dist` is continuously read and appended new elements.
Someone in the past suggested to me that lists may be better than matrices for read/write. If that is the case, I could write out `pairwise.dist` as a named list.

BTW, just FYI, in this specific example the full distance matrix is calculated quite fast:

```
system.time(ddu.dist <- dist(ddu.tab, method = "binary"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.61    0.00    0.61
```

which seems to indicate that there is indeed a fast method to calculate binary distances.

If anyone could please advise and/or point me to relevant resources, it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: On your second question, it will be much faster if you create `pairwise.dist` as a matrix of the correct dimensions up front, and just assign the values as you go, rather than `rbind`ing.

Comment: Thanks Andrew; however, I tried what you suggest and it was much slower. I made a sparse matrix full of 0's, and assigned its elements one by one within the loop. Could you please show an example that works better than the above?

Comment: I was just thinking to set `pairwise.dist <- matrix(NA, nrow=40000, ncol=3)`, set an incremental counter `k` within the loop, and replace your commented out line with `pairwise.dist[k,] <- c(min(i,j),max(i,j),dij)`.  But my suggestion below would be faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about speeding up the distance function itself, but you could replace your double loop, using the `tidyverse`, with

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- crossing(x = x, y = y) %>%             #all x,y combinations
  filter(x < y) %>%                               #remove duplicates
  mutate(pairwise.dist = map2_dbl(x, y, distfun)) #apply distance function
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew; I could also use `sapply`; here I was more concerned about the distance function and the efficient storage of the calculated distances, as explained.